# Como simular uma função de click em um arquivo HTML utilizando o Jest?

Tags: javascript, jest

Estou começando a criar testes para uma página simples em HTML, ela possui um script com algumas funções e a minha idéia é testar essas funções.

Porém não consigo simular um click no DOM dentro do meu teste, como posso fazer isso? Lembrando que não estou utilizando nenhum framework, é apenas JS/HTML.

Segue o exemplo do que estou fazendo:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const html = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, '../../index.html'), 'utf8');
// Manipulate DOM
document.body.innerHTML = html;


const saveData = function(idStore, idEmployee, apiKey, journey){
       localStorage.setItem("idStore", idStore);
}

describe("Save Function", () => {
    test("Testing if data is saved to localStorage", () => {

        let idStore = document.getElementById('idStore');
        idStore.value = '123456'
        let btn = document.getElementById('saveButton');

btn.onclick = function(){
            saveData(idStore.value);
        }


        btn.click();
        expect(localStorage.getItem('idStore')).toEqual('123456');
    });
  });
```

Ao rodar o teste, o valor recebido pelo 'idStore' continua nulo, como se o click não tivesse sido executado.

Comment: E se colocar o except() dentro do .onclick após o saveData, o que ocorre?

Comment: fazendo isso o teste sempre dá ok, acredito que achei uma forma, porém não é o que eu queria

Comment: O evento click ao ser executado não ocorrerá exatamente na sequencia, ou melhor não irá bloquear as proximas instruções do script, logo em poucos milionésimos de segundo a função fora, except(), consegue executar antes de .click(). Creio que seja isto